# Compare last characters of strings

Tags: string, matlab

I need to compare the last characters of strings in matlab. Natively I would do the following:

```
string = 'foobar';
len_string = length(string);
if len_str_2 >= 3
   str_suffix = str_2(len_str_2 - 2:len_str_2);
   strcmp('bar', str_suffix)
end
```

Is there a simpler way to do this? With `strncmp` I can only compare the first `n` characters.

Comment: This is just one specific case of trying to find a pattern in a string. In general `regexp` is a good tool for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds like a typical job for a regular expression:

```
any(regexp('foobar','bar$'))  %% Will return true
any(regexp('foobars','bar$')) %% Will return false
```

The dollar sign enforces the pattern to be at the end of the string.

Answer (score 3):

Later Matlab has function `endsWith`, but it will take me a while to start to use it due to the worry of compatibility.

```
str = 'foobar';
endsWith(str, 'bar') % return logical 1
```

Comment: FYI, endsWith along with several other new text functions were added in 16b.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `end` to refer to the last character of the string.

```
string = 'foobar';

if length(string) >= 3
    matches = strcmp('bar', string(end-2:end))
end
```

If eliminating the `if` statement is crucial, you could use `max`, but this definitely seems less desirable to me:

```
string = 'foobar';
search_str = 'bar';

matches = strcmp(search_str, string(max(end-length(search_str)+1, 1)
```

Comment: Better than mine, but the check (lenght(string) > 3) is still required.

Comment: @jonie83 Added a variation that does not use `if`, though I think the first is still the better of these two, as the code is much more readable.

Answer (score 2):

You can flip left-to-right `string` and `search string` and then use `strncmp` -

```
%// Inputs
string = 'foobar'
search_string = 'bar'

out = strncmp(string(end:-1:1),search_string(end:-1:1),numel(search_string))
```

Few sample runs -

**(1) Original problem case**

```
string =
foobar
search_string =
bar
out =
     1
```

**(2) Modified case with `string` same as `search_string`**

```
string =
bar
search_string =
bar
out =
     1
```

**(3) Modified case with `string` of smaller length than `search_string`, for which you had the `IF` conditional**

```
string =
ar
search_string =
bar
out =
     0
```

Comment: Nicely done. Any reason to use both `string(end:-1:1)` and `fliplr` for the two different string?

Comment: @ohruunuruus No big reason really, but with the initial tests, I had the search_string hard-coded, so fliplr was used then. Edited with `(end:-1:1)` and this should save the function call to `fliplr` and could be a tad faster.